# pmcore Asset is not a valid PDF

Tags: pimcore

I have copy a new Pimcore pro on my webserver.
When I drag and drop a PDF Asset in documents it shows the Message **`"Asset is not a valid PDF. Sorry! Somthing went wrong."`**

At Assets I can watch the PDF and at the Documents looks that it link is ok = Dependencies works! But I can't see the preview or in frontend.

What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Check two things:

1. Is there PDF lib install on web server?

   - You can install the PDF lib by following [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.installation.php). You can check all the install library in setting from admin panel.
2. Is there full permission (0777) on **/website/var** folder and **/pimcore** folder?

   - You can give the permission by using the control panel (If it is provided by server service provider) or by using the command `sudo chmod -R 0777 /website/var/*` .

Mostly such issues arise due to permission when pimcore try to upload any file on server.

Comment: Ok I have changed the directories to 0777 both, that was 755 only. But that wasnt it alone. Now I will look about this PDF lib, but seems thats not easy for me. Isn't this the correct packe for me? => ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libtool/

Comment: @LarsWichmann No that is not that lib. check on php.net for other ways